# JsonException: Unable to parse: request content-length too big or unknown

Tags: selenium-webdriver, intellij-idea, selenide, autotest

I get an error when I try to upload a file in input field: JsonException: Unable to parse: request content-length too big or unknown.

But before I get such an error, ide starts behaving strangely.It just hangs on the method of loading the file and then the program does not continue execution, but does not stop either. I did not make any changes, before the test worked fine.The rest of the tests with files work fine, this file is the largest, it exceeds 200 megabytes. IDE bag ?

Method:

```
uploadUpdateInput.sendKeys("src/main/resources/file");
```

Full stacktrace:

```
JsonException: Unable to parse: request content-length too big or unknown.
Screenshot: file:/home/fesb/2/9QHH7zUD0z/build/reports/tests/1685366187236.0.png
Page source: file:/home/fesb/2/9QHH7zUD0z/build/reports/tests/1685366187236.0.html
Timeout: 20 s.
Caused by: json.JsonException: Unable to parse: request content-length too big or unknown.

    at com.codeborne.selenide.ex.UIAssertionError.wrapToUIAssertionError(UIAssertionError.java:103)
    at com.codeborne.selenide.ex.UIAssertionError.wrapThrowable(UIAssertionError.java:86)
    at com.codeborne.selenide.ex.UIAssertionError.wrap(UIAssertionError.java:80)
    at com.codeborne.selenide.impl.SelenideElementProxy.invoke(SelenideElementProxy.java:91)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy14.sendKeys(Unknown Source)
    at ru.factorts.page.UpdatePage.update(UpdatePage.java:39)
    at ru.factorts.page.Update.update(Update.java:138)
    at ru.factorts.page.N6_SystemSingleTest.aUpdate(N6_SystemSingleTest.java:251)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
    at org.junit.rules.TestWatcher$1.evaluate(TestWatcher.java:55)
    at org.junit.rules.RunRules.evaluate(RunRules.java:20)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at junitparams.JUnitParamsRunner.runChild(JUnitParamsRunner.java:449)
    at junitparams.JUnitParamsRunner.runChild(JUnitParamsRunner.java:393)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:69)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater$1.execute(IdeaTestRunner.java:38)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.TestsRepeater.repeat(TestsRepeater.java:11)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:35)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:232)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:55)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.json.JsonException: Unable to parse: request content-length too big or unknown.
    at org.openqa.selenium.json.Json.toType(Json.java:57)
    at org.openqa.selenium.json.Json.toType(Json.java:50)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.codec.w3c.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:99)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.codec.w3c.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:53)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:184)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:547)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.execute(RemoteWebElement.java:257)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.upload(RemoteWebElement.java:123)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193)
    at java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1384)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:482)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:472)
    at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:708)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:566)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.sendKeys(RemoteWebElement.java:110)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.codeborne.selenide.impl.SelenideElementProxy.dispatchAndRetry(SelenideElementProxy.java:132)
    at com.codeborne.selenide.impl.SelenideElementProxy.invoke(SelenideElementProxy.java:81)
    ... 34 more
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.json.JsonException: Unable to determine type from: r. Last 1 characters read: r
Build info: version: '4.4.0', revision: 'e5c75ed026a'
System info: host: 'test01-virtual-machine', ip: '192.168.57.240', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '5.4.0-149-generic', java.version: '1.8.0_352'
Driver info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriver
    at org.openqa.selenium.json.JsonInput.peek(JsonInput.java:126)
    at org.openqa.selenium.json.JsonTypeCoercer.lambda$buildCoercer$6(JsonTypeCoercer.java:141)
    at org.openqa.selenium.json.JsonTypeCoercer.coerce(JsonTypeCoercer.java:127)
    at org.openqa.selenium.json.Json.toType(Json.java:71)
    at org.openqa.selenium.json.Json.toType(Json.java:55)
    ... 55 more
```